# perl cpanminus error installing GD::Image cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fstack-protector"

Tags: perl, installation, cpan

I'm using cpanm to install GD::Image. This is on a Linux system with no root privileges, so I thought this would be the easiest way.

Apparently GD compilation fails:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.4007 on perl 5.008008 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Work directory is /homes/avilella/.cpanm/work/1310719630.11564
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching GD::Image on cpanmetadb ...
-> FAIL Finding GD::Image on cpanmetadb failed.
Searching GD::Image on search.cpan.org ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.31 ... Yes (6.58)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Install 1.46 ... Yes (1.54)
Checking if you have Module::Build 0.36 ... No
==> Found dependencies: Module::Build
Searching Module::Build on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Module::Build
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/Module-Build-0.3800.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Module-Build-0.3800.tar.gz
Entering Module-Build-0.3800
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Configuring Module-Build-0.3800
Running Build.PL
Checking prerequisites...
  requires:
    !  ExtUtils::CBuilder is not installed

Checking optional features...
dist_authoring..........disabled
  requires:
    ! Archive::Tar is not installed
  recommends:
    * Pod::Readme is not installed

ERRORS/WARNINGS FOUND IN PREREQUISITES.  You may wish to install the versions
of the modules indicated above before proceeding with this installation

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Module-Build' version '0.3800'
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.yml ...
Checking if you have Module::Metadata 1.000002 ... Yes (1.000004)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0.82 ... Yes (3.12)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Install 0 ... Yes (1.54)
Checking if you have File::Compare 0 ... Yes (1.1003)
Checking if you have File::Find 0 ... Yes (1.10)
Checking if you have File::Path 0 ... Yes (1.08)
Checking if you have CPAN::Meta 2.110420 ... Yes (2.110930001)
Checking if you have Perl::OSType 1 ... Yes (1.002)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::CBuilder 0.27 ... No
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Manifest 0 ... Yes (1.58)
Checking if you have Text::Abbrev 0 ... Yes (1.01)
Checking if you have Test::Harness 0 ... Yes (3.23)
Checking if you have File::Copy 0 ... Yes (2.09)
Checking if you have Getopt::Long 0 ... Yes (2.35)
Checking if you have IO::File 0 ... Yes (1.13)
Checking if you have version 0.87 ... Yes (0.88)
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.121_08)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::ParseXS 2.21 ... Yes (2.2206)
Checking if you have Text::ParseWords 0 ... Yes (3.24)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.74)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Mkbootstrap 0 ... Yes (6.58)
Checking if you have Cwd 0 ... Yes (3.12)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.49 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Test::Harness 3.16 ... Yes (3.23)
Checking if you have Parse::CPAN::Meta 1.4401 ... Yes (1.4401)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0.15 ... Yes (0.22)
==> Found dependencies: ExtUtils::CBuilder
Searching ExtUtils::CBuilder on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on ExtUtils::CBuilder
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.280202.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.280202.tar.gz
Entering ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.280202
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.31 ... Yes (6.58)
Configuring ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.280202
Running Makefile.PL
Warning: prerequisite File::Spec 3.13 not found. We have 3.12.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for ExtUtils::CBuilder
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.yml ...
Finding PREREQ from Makefile ...
Checking if you have Text::ParseWords 0 ... Yes (3.24)
Checking if you have IO::File 0 ... Yes (1.13)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0 ... Yes (0.22)
Checking if you have File::Spec 3.13 ... No (3.12 < 3.13)
Checking if you have IPC::Cmd 0 ... Yes (0.72)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.74)
Checking if you have Cwd 0 ... Yes (3.12)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.47 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Test::More 0.47 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Text::ParseWords 0 ... Yes (3.24)
Checking if you have IO::File 0 ... Yes (1.13)
Checking if you have File::Temp 0 ... Yes (0.22)
Checking if you have IPC::Cmd 0 ... Yes (0.72)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.74)
Checking if you have Cwd 0 ... Yes (3.12)
==> Found dependencies: File::Spec
Searching File::Spec on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on File::Spec
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SM/SMUELLER/PathTools-3.33.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking PathTools-3.33.tar.gz
Entering PathTools-3.33
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.58)
Configuring PathTools-3.33
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Cwd
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.yml ...
Finding PREREQ from Makefile ...
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.21)
Checking if you have Test 0 ... Yes (1.25)
Checking if you have File::Path 0 ... Yes (1.08)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.74)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.04)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.58)
Checking if you have Scalar::Util 0 ... Yes (1.21)
Checking if you have Test 0 ... Yes (1.25)
Checking if you have File::Path 0 ... Yes (1.08)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.74)
Checking if you have Carp 0 ... Yes (1.04)
Building PathTools-3.33
cp lib/File/Spec/OS2.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/OS2.pm
cp lib/File/Spec/Mac.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/Mac.pm
cp lib/File/Spec/VMS.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/VMS.pm
cp lib/File/Spec/Cygwin.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/Cygwin.pm
cp lib/File/Spec/Functions.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/Functions.pm
cp lib/File/Spec/Epoc.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/Epoc.pm
cp lib/File/Spec.pm blib/lib/File/Spec.pm
cp Cwd.pm blib/lib/Cwd.pm
cp lib/File/Spec/Unix.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/Unix.pm
cp lib/File/Spec/Win32.pm blib/lib/File/Spec/Win32.pm
/usr/bin/perl /homes/avilella/src/lookseq/lookseq/deps/lib/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap  Cwd.xs > Cwd.xsc && mv Cwd.xsc Cwd.c
gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"3.33\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.33\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   Cwd.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fstack-protector"
cc1: error: invalid parameter `ssp-buffer-size'
Cwd.c:1: error: bad value (generic) for -mtune= switch
make: *** [Cwd.o] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing File::Spec failed. See /homes/avilella/.cpanm/build.log for details.
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for ExtUtils-CBuilder-0.280202. Retry with --prompt or --force.
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for Module-Build-0.3800. Retry with --prompt or --force.
--> Working on GD::Image
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/L/LD/LDS/GD-2.46.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking GD-2.46.tar.gz
Entering GD-2.46
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.58)
Configuring GD-2.46
Running Makefile.PL
Notice: Type perl Makefile.PL -h for command-line option summary.

Configuring for libgd version 2.0.33.
Checking for stray libgd header files...

** WARNING: found gd.h header file in /usr/includegd.h, but it is expected at /ebi/research/software/Linux_x86_64/opt/stow/gd-2.0.33/include/gd.h. This may cause compile errors! **


** WARNING: found gd.h header file in /usr/includegd.h, but it is expected at /ebi/research/software/Linux_x86_64/opt/stow/gd-2.0.33/include/gd.h. This may cause compile errors! **
** Possible problems found **

Included Features:          GD_XPM GD_JPEG GD_FONTCONFIG GD_FREETYPE GD_PNG GD_GIF GD_UNCLOSEDPOLY GD_ANIMGIF GD_FTCIRCLE VERSION_33
GD library used from:       /ebi/research/software/Linux_x86_64/opt/stow/gd-2.0.33
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for GD
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.yml ...
Finding PREREQ from Makefile ...
Checking if you have Math::Trig 0 ... Yes (1.03)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.58)
Checking if you have Math::Trig 0 ... Yes (1.03)
Building and testing GD-2.46
/usr/bin/perl GD/Image.pm.PLS GD/Image.pm
Extracting Image.pm (with variable substitutions)
cp GD/Polyline.pm blib/lib/GD/Polyline.pm
cp qd.pl blib/lib/qd.pl
cp GD/Image.pm blib/lib/GD/Image.pm
cp GD.pm blib/lib/GD.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/GD.pm (blib/lib/auto/GD)
cp GD/Simple.pm blib/lib/GD/Simple.pm
cp GD/Polygon.pm blib/lib/GD/Polygon.pm
cp GD/Group.pm blib/lib/GD/Group.pm
/usr/bin/perl /homes/avilella/src/lookseq/lookseq/deps/lib/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  GD.xs > GD.xsc && mv GD.xsc GD.c
gcc -c  -I/ebi/research/software/Linux_x86_64/opt/stow/gd-2.0.33/include -Wformat=0 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"2.46\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.46\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -DHAVE_JPEG -DHAVE_FT -DHAVE_XPM -DHAVE_GIF -DHAVE_PNG -DHAVE_ANIMGIF -DVERSION_33 -DHAVE_UNCLOSEDPOLY -DHAVE_FONTCONFIG -DHAVE_FTCIRCLE GD.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fstack-protector"
cc1: error: invalid parameter `ssp-buffer-size'
GD.c:1: error: bad value (generic) for -mtune= switch
make: *** [GD.o] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing GD::Image failed. See /homes/avilella/.cpanm/build.log for details.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cpanm` doesn't have special support for installation without root rights if you use the system perl.

1) You can use [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App%3a%3aperlbrew) and compile your own perl into your home. After that you can just use cpanm in your "home perl".

2) You can use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3a%3alib) it sets up an environment that uses the system perl, but you install the modules to your home directory. After you did the setup described in local::lib it can work with cpanm.

If it still fails to install. Please provide the full log. cpanm says at the end that detailed information are in "/homes/avilella/.cpanm/build.log". If you install XS Modules sometimes you need to install some header files or other stuff. From the error messages from the build log you often can see why it fails. But you need to provide the file.

Comment: I see, where do I put the log file?

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. cpanm detects situation and invokes its special support for non-root inst.: `$ cpanm Text::Template␤! Can't write to /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 and /usr/local/bin: Installing modules to /home/user/perl5␤! To turn off this warning […]:␤!   - run me as a root or with --sudo option (to install to /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 and /usr/local/bin)␤|   - run me with --local-lib option e.g. cpanm --local-lib=~/perl5␤!   - Set PERL_CPANM_OPT="--local-lib=~/perl5" environment variable (in your shell rc file)␤!   - Configure local::lib in your shell to set PERL_MM_OPT etc.`

Comment: @daxim
Half-true. It detects if it can write to the directory. If not it sets up local::lib for you. 

@avilella
Just add it to the question.